# how to make my horizontal css dock navigation to vertical

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, hover, dock

I can now see the text/caption after changing some codes. The problem now is that, instead of vertical, i have it on horizontal. Please help me on how to transform the dock navigation to vertical. Thank you :)

Here are the codes I used:

***CSS**

```
#navigation {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:300;
}

.expand-down {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height:normal;
  margin-top:20px;
  height:150px;
  width:500px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
.expand-down * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.expand-down ul {
  padding-top:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.expand-down ul li {
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
}
.expand-down ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.expand-down ul li a img {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  border:none;
}
.expand-down ul li a span {
  display:none;
}
.expand-down ul li:hover a span {
  display:block;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
  color:red;
}
.expand-down ul li:hover a img {
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
}
.expand-down ul li:hover + li a img {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
}
.expand-down ul li:hover + li + li a img {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
}
```

***HTML**

```
 <div id="navigation">

  <div class="expand-down" align="left">
   <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="timaHOME.php" onClick="playSound("beep-02.wav");"><img src="home icon1.png"/><span>HOME</span></a>
    </li> <br />

    <li>
      <a href="timaREGISTER.php" onClick="playSound("beep-02.wav");"><img src="profile icon.png"/><span>REGISTER</span></a>
    </li> 
    <br />

    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="report icon.png"/><span>REPORTS</span></a>
    </li> <br />
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you link to the Fisheye() plug-in you're using? And show the html *including* the `#dock2` element to which you're applying the plug-in?

Comment: Looks like you're using jquery. You should add that as a tag.

Comment: hi! i edited it out already :) i refused to use the jquery since it'll conflict my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this `float:left;`

```
.expand-down ul li {
  float:left; //REMOVE
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/2pyu3/

**EDIT**

To make the caption line up beside the image, add a `display:inline-block;`

```
.expand-down ul li:hover a span {
  display:inline-block; //CHANGE THIS
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/2pyu3/1/

Comment: my pleasure, @Mae.  If this answered the question, feel free to click the checkmark at the side.

Comment: i'm still having problem with the caption though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.expand-down ul li {
  list-style-type:none;
}

.expand-down ul li:hover a span {
  display:block;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:left;
  color:red;
}
```

see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/p9PyC/2/)